# (Straight line) Gradient for (-4, 0) (0, 2.5)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fractions

So I changed the question the textbook gave me to (-4,0) (0, 5/2).

The question asked me what is the gradient for the X and Y.I was doing the question without a calculator and the answer I got was 8/5.

But when I checked the calculator, it shows up 5/8 for me?

On how I got 8/5 manually was when I'm left with 5/2 over 4(not 5/2/4).So I changed the question from 5/2 over 4 to 2/5 times 4.The reason why I did this is because I remembered if a fraction divides with a number, all you need to do is flip the denominator and the numerator and times only the updated numerator with 4.Thus, 8/5.

But the 5/8 the calculator gave me was derived by me pressing 5/2 divide 4.

So which one is the right answer? The 8/5 that I got manually or the 5/8 that I got through using the calculator.Can someone also elucidate on why you think the answer you chose is correct?

Comment: What are you even calculating, and how is this "algebraic geometry"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what tag to put this question. I'm doing straight lines. I need to find the gradient for (-4, 0) and (0, 5/2)

Comment: Geez, what's with the downvotes here? The question and mistake are elementary, but this site officially welcomes questions at _all_ levels -- and the OP explains very nicely and completely what he's doing to get his wrong result. That's an _impeccable_ question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{a}{b}$ ÷ $\frac{c}{d}$

= $\frac{a}{b} *\frac{d}{c}$

Where $\frac{d}{c}$ is known as the *reciprocal* of $\frac{c}{d}$

So $\frac{\frac{5}{2} -0}{0-(-4)} = \frac{\frac{5}{2}}{4} =\frac{5}{2} ÷ \frac{4}{1} = \frac{5}{2} * \frac{1}{4} = \frac{5}{8}$

So your error was that you "flipped" the fraction you were dividing, rather than "flipping" the number you divided by.

Comment: I know the I shouldn't be typing thanks but Thanks !